# Play framework: read Json containing null values

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to read Json data in my Play Scala program. The Json may contain nulls in some fields, so this is how I defined the Reads object:

```
  implicit val readObj: Reads[ApplyRequest] = (
      (JsPath \ "a").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "b").read[Option[String]] and
      (JsPath \ "c").read[Option[String]] and
      (JsPath \ "d").read[Option[Int]]
    )  (ApplyRequest.apply _)
```

And the ApplyRequest case class:

```
case class ApplyRequest ( a: String,
                          b: Option[String],
                          c: Option[String],
                          d: Option[Int],
                          )
```

This does not compile, I get `No Json deserializer found for type Option[String]. Try to implement an implicit Reads or Format for this type.`

How to declare the Reads object to accept possible nulls?

Comment: do you use `import play.api.libs.json._` ?

Comment: yes, that's the import I'm using

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`readNullable`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.JsPath@readNullable[T](implicitr:play.api.libs.json.Reads[T]):play.api.libs.json.Reads[Option[T]]) to parse missing or `null` fields:

```
implicit val readObj: Reads[ApplyRequest] = (
  (JsPath \ "a").read[String] and
  (JsPath \ "b").readNullable[String] and
  (JsPath \ "c").readNullable[String] and
  (JsPath \ "d").readNullable[Int]
)  (ApplyRequest.apply _)
```