# Play framework: Reading possibily null value into string "null" instead of Option[String]

Tags: scala, playframework

My issue is similar to this one: [Play framework: read Json containing null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35505969/play-framework-read-json-containing-null-values/35506197)

```
implicit val readObj: Reads[ApplyRequest] = (
  (JsPath \ "a").read[String] and
  (JsPath \ "b").readNullable[String] and
  (JsPath \ "c").readNullable[String] and
  (JsPath \ "d").readNullable[Int]
)  (ApplyRequest.apply _)
```

Except instead of parsing a potentially null value into an Option[String], I would like one of these values to be a String, but allow the value being parsed in to be the string "null" if the value is absent or null.

ie.

```
implicit val readObj: Reads[ApplyRequest] = (
  (JsPath \ "a").read[String] and
  (JsPath \ "b").read[String] and // this can be null, but should turn into string "null"
  (JsPath \ "c").readNullable[String] and
  (JsPath \ "d").readNullable[Int]
)  (ApplyRequest.apply _)
```

Is this possible? What's a clean way of doing this?

We're unfortunately using version 2.4 so don't have the default behavior in 2.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible by using the `readWithDefault` method.

Having:

```
case class ApplyRequest(a: String, b: String, c: Option[String], d: Option[Int])

private val json =
"""
  |{
  |  "a": "test1",
  |  "b": null,
  |  "c": null,
  |  "d": 1
  |}
""".stripMargin
```

The `Reads` is defined:

```
implicit val readObj: Reads[ApplyRequest] = (
    (JsPath \ "a").read[String] and
    (JsPath \ "b").readWithDefault[String]("null") and // default value here
    (JsPath \ "c").readNullable[String] and
    (JsPath \ "d").readNullable[Int]
  ) (ApplyRequest.apply _)
```

Parsed:

```
val parsedJsValue = Json.parse(json)
val parsedApplyRequest = Json.fromJson[ApplyRequest](parsedJsValue).get
println(parsedApplyRequest)            // ApplyRequest(test1,null,None,Some(1))
println(parsedApplyRequest.b.getClass) // class java.lang.String
```

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like we are stuck on version 2.4 and this only works in 2.6+ , but I'll see if we can upgrade

Comment: If you don't have access to `readWithDefault`, you could possibly use `readNullable`, then instead of `ApplyRequest.apply _` be explicit with `(a:String, b:Option[String], c:Option[String], d:Option[Int]) => ApplyRequest(a,b.getOrElse("null"),c,d)`